# How to use multi inputs or multi features for RNN or LSTM

Tags: time-series, deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a time series dataframe like blow, and the number in it is meaning less, and I have some problems when applying LSTM.

I have saw some demos of LSTM, mostly use this pattern: `[y_{t-2},y_{t-1},y_{t}] to predict [y_{t+1}]`, but just as the dataframe blow, I also have `featureA, featureB, featureC`, so my quesiton is: how to use multi inputs or multi features for LSTM

```
time    featureA    featureB    featureC    target
1   2   5   6   1
2   4   1   7   3
3   6   2   1   5
4   2   4   0   7
5   7   6   1   5
6   9   3   2   8
7   1   2   3   5
8   2   9   5   10
9   1   10  7   6
10  3   2   2   11
```

Answer (score 0):

For RNN/LSTM, it is more like this: `[..., y_{t-2}(x_{t-2}), y_{t-1}(x_{t-1})]` to predict `[y_{t}(x_{t})]`

Or more succinctly:

```
y_{t} = f(y_{t-1}, x_{t})
```

So in feed forward you still use your inputs `x_{t}` (i.e. your features) plus the outputs from previous timesteps to make the prediction at the current timestep.